# UNIX ZIP command produces a corrupt zip file

Tags: linux, zip, opensuse

On my openSUSE machine, I am trying to zip some big files (some GBs of magnitude) using the built-in ZIP command from UNIX. However after the compression is done, I've tried to test if everything was done successfully but it gives following error:

```
zip warning: local header not found for myfile
zip error: Zip file structure invalid myfile.zip
```

Do you know any other command tools or programs that can generate ZIP-compatible output? Before trying to write it in Java (not sure if ZIP64 is supported yet under Java 6 SE), I would like to ask if something is out there ready.

Comment: Yeah, your comment is quite fair. Do you know if I can have support of ZIP64 in Java 6 SE? I read that it will be supported in Java 7, but not in existing versions of java 6.

Comment: Upgrade your version. Mine used to do that but it no longer does and I am not even at the latest. Zip 2.32 compiled GCC 4.4.1 on 2009-10-24 under OpenSUSE 11.2 64-bits. I assume anything newer will do it too.